# Segunda conexión en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo este problema, tengo que conectarme a dos bases de datos, la conexión de inicio funciona correctamente, pero al hacer la segunda conexión quisiera ver si es posible mantener la segunda conexión y desconectar en el momento que yo quisiera, dejo mi código:

PD: Únicamente para cambiar de base de datos necesito cambiar el `host` y el nombre de la base de datos.

Aquí envió los valores del `host` y nombre de la base de datos y los almaceno en cache, pero no quisiera usar cache, en lugar de eso que quede conectado, y desconectarlo también borrar los datos de la segunda conexión.

```
 public conexion1(){
     $array = [
            'host' => $r->Host,
            'bd' => $r->BaseDatos,
            
           ];
    //envió los datos a una variable cache
     cache(['database_config' => $array], null);

 $this->confBd();
$sp1 = DB::connection('sqlsrv_second')->select('EXEC hola');
    }
```

Función que carga los datos de la segunda conexión.

```
protected function confBd(){
   
try {
//llamo a la variable cache
        $config = cache('database_config');
        $host=$config['host'];
        $bd=$config['bd'];   

   
     config(['database.connections.sqlsrv_second.host' => $host]);
    //aqui cambio el nombre de la base de datos
    config(['database.connections.sqlsrv_second.database' => $bd]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    
}
```

Archivo .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=host.dyndns.org
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=hola
DB_USERNAME=A
DB_PASSWORD=CC

DB_CONNECTION_SECONDS=sqlsrv
DB_HOST_SECONDS=null
DB_PORT_SECONDS=1433
DB_DATABASE_SECONDS=null
DB_USERNAME_SECONDS=A
DB_PASSWORD_SECONDS=CC
```

Archivo database.php

```
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
     'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'true'),
],

'sqlsrv_second' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL_SECONDS'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECONDS'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECONDS', '1433'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SECONDS'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SECONDS', ''),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECONDS', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
     'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'true'),
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agradezco la ayuda, para la persona que tenga que conectarse a una segunda base de datos solo debes crear una segunda conexion en el .env y en el archivo database.php así como lo coloque, si en la segunda conexión hay campos que no se necesitan ser dinámicos puedes dejarlos llenos y los dinamicos dejarlos vacios ejemplo:

archivo .env

```
DB_CONNECTION_SECONDS=sqlsrv
DB_HOST_SECONDS=
DB_PORT_SECONDS=1433
DB_DATABAS_SECONDS=
DB_USERNAME_SECONDS=usuario
DB_PASSWORD_SECONDS=usuario1
```

archivo database.php

```
 'sqlsrv_second' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL_SECONDS'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECONDS','' ),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECONDS', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SECONDS', ''),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SECONDS', 'Usuario'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECONDS', 'Usuario1'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
             'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'true'),
        ],
```

En mi caso solo los campos dinámicos son host y database así que los dejo vacíos, luego de eso en cada función solicito el host y base de datos por medio del request y con eso hago el cambio.

```
public function login(Request $request){
//nombre de la base de datos se obtiene con el request
      $bd = $request->input('bd');
//nombre del host se obtiene con el request
       $h = $request->input('h');

//y lleno los campos dinamicos que habia dejado vacio   
      config(['database.connections.sqlsrv_second.host' => $h]);
      config(['database.connections.sqlsrv_second.database' => $bd]);

//ejecuto la conexion dinamica y hago la consulta
     $segunda_conexion = DB::connection('sqlsrv_second')->select(ejecuto la consulta);
}
```

Explicación de la problemática:
Primero, ejecuto un procedimiento almacenado en la primera conexión. Este procedimiento me proporciona el host y el nombre de la base de datos a la que necesito realizar consultas. Luego, envío estos datos, junto con los de conexión, como respuesta a mi aplicación y los guardo. De esta forma, solo necesito enviar los parámetros, host y nombre de la base de datos al realizar consultas en la segunda base de datos, es decir que repito esto en cada una de las funciones de mi controlador.

Answer (score 1):

En PHP no existe el concepto de un pool de conexiones independiente del request (o del script cuando es CLI).

Toda operación que se haga hacia la BBDD existe dentro de una conexión que se instancia durante el request y muere junto con éste o bien cuando la cierras explícitamente.

(En ambiente CLI, en ausencia de un request, la conexión vive durante el tiempo de ejecución del script).

Por lo anterior, no tiene sentido pasar por el caché como lo estás haciendo. En la práctica tu implementación resulta una milesima de segundo más lenta por su uso.

Comment: al final guarde los datos del cache en otro tipo de variables y quedo asi:     protected function confBd(){

try {
        $config = cache('database_config');
        $host=$config['host'];
        $bd=$config['bd'];
        
        define('HOST',$host);
        define('BD',$bd);
        
        $host2=constant('HOST');
        $bd2=constant('BD');
 
     config(['database.connections.sqlsrv_second.host' => $host2]);

    config(['database.connections.sqlsrv_second.database' => $bd2]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    
}

    }

Answer (score 0):

En Laravel podés usar múltiples DB siempre que estén correctamente declaradas en database.php y que las variables estén correctamente definidas en el .env.

Vas a tener una base por default que es la primera que se creó, en este caso: 'sqlsrv'.

Cuando hagas una consulta va a apuntar a esa directamente:

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Lo antes mencionado apuntaría a hola.users

En cambio, si necesitás hacer la misma consulta a la otra db, debés apuntar la canexión usando connection():

```
DB::connection('sqlsrv_second')->table('users')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

En este caso apuntaría a null.users

Para ahorrar problemas a largo plazo recomiendo siempre especificar la conexión cuando se usan dos o más bases de datos. Por tanto la primer consulta debería quedarte así:

```
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('users')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Con todo lo dicho anteriormente, no es necesario hacer funciones adicionales como confBd(). Laravel está preparado para estos casos y la forma (bastante sencilla, por cierto) es esta.

Comment: lo que pasa es que el host y database son dinámicos y cambian por esos tuve que hace una función para cargar los nuevos datos.